# YII_ENV being ignored when including config

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have setup a new Yii2 advanced instance and ran `init` to set my local environment to `dev`. However the config files in `environments/dev/*` are being ignored. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Have you got proper entry in `environments/index.php`?

Comment: I believe that I do. It looks fine.

Comment: Although it appears that `environments/index.php` is not being included by Yii either.